# Averaging contents of files based on a certain criterion uin Python

Tags: python, operating-system

I am scanning 2 folders each with the same file name. I want to take average of the contents in these files which meet a certain criterion shown below. I present the contents of each file as well as the current and expected outputs.

```
import os

NFILES = 3

values = [[] for _ in range(NFILES)]

k = 0.5  # fraction of initial number of invaded pores
K = 1.0e3
Cb0 = 0.001
DiffCoeff = 1e-8

for i in range(NFILES):
    filepath = rf"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Basics\Averaged_Testing\{i}\len_J_{K}_{Cb0}_{DiffCoeff}.txt"
    if os.path.isfile(filepath):
        with open(filepath) as data:
            lines = data.readlines()
            numbers = [float(line.strip()) for line in lines if line.strip().isdigit()]
            if numbers and min(numbers) <= k * max(numbers):
                values[i].extend(numbers)
                print("Folder numbers which meet the criterion =", i)

valid_values = [v for v in values if v]  # Remove empty lists

print("Total number of folders which meet the criterion =", len(valid_values))

max_length = max(len(inner_list) for inner_list in valid_values)

averaged_values = []
for sublist in zip(*valid_values):
    sublist_avg = sum(sublist) / len(valid_values)
    averaged_values.append(sublist_avg)

print("Averaged values:")
for avg_value in averaged_values:
    print(avg_value)

with open(rf"C:\Users\USER\OneDrive - Technion\Research_Technion\Python_PNM\Basics\Averaged_Testing\Averaged_{k}__{K}_{Cb0}_{DiffCoeff}_{NFILES}files.txt", 'w') as f:
    for avg_value in averaged_values:
        f.write(str(avg_value) + '\n')
```

The contents of the file in folder `1` are

```
405
405
400
311
105
35
14
4
3
3
```

The contents of the file in folder `2` are

```
411
411
393
139
35
8
0
```

The current output is

```
408.0
408.0
396.5
225.0
70.0
21.5
7.0
```

The expected output is

```
408.0
408.0
396.5
225.0
70.0
21.5
14.0
4.0
3.0
3.0
```

Comment: zip is your problem. Your sub-lists are of differing lengths. zip will stop iterating after the shortest list is exhausted

Comment: Use `zip_longest` instead of `zip`.

Comment: I used ```zip_longest``` but it says I need to define it. I don't know how to define it.

Comment: You can't use zip_longest for this. What would you use for the fillvalue? Let's say you used zero as the fillvalue then your last output value would be 1.5 in this case because len(valid_values) == 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleted my previous post as it was only for 2 files. For n files:

```py
lines1 = [405, 405, 400, 311, 105, 35, 14, 4, 3, 3 ]
lines2 = [411, 411, 393, 139, 35, 8, 0]
lines3 = []
files_contents = {"filename1":lines1, "filename2":lines2}  # "filename":[line1, line2, line3]

for i in range(max([len(v) for v in files_contents.values()])):
    v3 = []
    for lines in files_contents.values():
        if i < len(lines):
            v3.append(lines1[i])
    lines3.append(sum(v3) / len(v3))  

print(lines3)  # [405.0, 405.0, 400.0, 311.0, 105.0, 35.0, 14.0, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

files_contents is a dict that maps the filenames to the list of lines of the files. In the example above there are only 2 files.